# How to display attached images in a jupyter notebook running in PyCharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I try to display an attached image or a video or any media in a markdown cell in the Jupyter Notebook, I end up with just blank squares. Is this a bug with the PyCharm IDE or are there additional steps to enable viewing media? Below is a screen shot of the problem. The attached .gif or any image for that matter just displays as a blank box. I have also checked if the problem is with the path.

[image]

If anyone was able to solve this please let me know. Thanks!